# How to merge an observable that is a property of another observable

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

I have a list of holidays each with a user id attached to them. I would like to merge the retrieved user data to each holiday record so it returns a single observable.

I created this function

```
getAllHolidaysAndUsers() {

  return this.af.database.list('Holiday').mergeMap(items => {
    for (let item of items) {
      item.user = this.af.database.object(`/User/${item.userIdKey}`);        
    }
    return items;

 });
}
```

it returns an object like this

```
{
  fromDate:'20/12/16',
  toDate:'21/12/16',
  user:fireBaseObservable
}
```

I would like an object like this

```
{
  fromDate:'20/12/16',
  toDate:'21/12/16',
  user:Array[1]
}
```

I am struggling to access the `user` observable in a single subscription. Currently I'm doing nested subscribes which I know is bad form.

I've managed to get a similar example working like this

```
getHolidayInfo() {
  return this.getHolidaysByUserId().mergeMap(hol => {

  return this.UserList.getUserByEmail().map(user => { 
    return {hol:hol.date, user:user[0]}
  });

});
```

But because I have to loop through `items` in the first example it only returns the last result, so this technique isn't working

[Here's the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/L3afagtLBfdscoShNKRl?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
getAllHolidaysAndUsers() {
  return this.holiday
    .switchMap(items => Observable.from(items))
    .flatMap(item => {
        return this.af.database.object(`/User/${item.userIdKey}`)
            .map(user => {
                item.user = user;
                return item;
            });
    })
    .toArray();
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question to show that holiday is a fireBaseListObservable. If I replace swtich map with the fireBaseListObservable flatMap (or mergeMap in rxjs5 ) gives typescript  alert 'property does not exist type any' on the userIdKey, which is causing issues. Why isn't firebase mapping over the array?

Comment: this depends on how you have typed your objects, you could try the following `${item["userIdKey"]}` - if that works, then it's a problem with using or incorrectly setting types at certain places, however it's hard to say without seeing more code, because in the code you provided you're not setting any types at all

Comment: I'll make a plunker, watch this space!